# get_xlim() not returning correct figure limits

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Wrote the following matplotlib based class to pan-right the figure using right arrow key. However, if I use the same class after zooming into the figure it does not produce the desired panning of the figure. I have figured out the root cause to be the get_xlim() function not returning the current or updated xlim of the figure. The right arrow key press event shows how get_xlim() seems to revert back to the old xlim values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

class NavFigure:
    ax_tmp = plt.gca()
    fig = plt.gcf()    

    def __init__(self):
        NavFigure.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.pan_nav)    

    def pan_nav(self, event):    
        if event.key == 'right':
            print("initial limits:", NavFigure.ax_tmp.get_xlim())
            lims = NavFigure.ax_tmp.get_xlim()
            adjust = (lims[1] - lims[0]) * 0.9            
            NavFigure.ax_tmp.set_xlim((lims[0] + adjust, lims[1] + adjust))
            plt.draw()
            NavFigure.ax_tmp = plt.gca()
            print("updated limits:", NavFigure.ax_tmp.get_xlim())

plt.plot(np.random.rand(100))   
myfig = NavFigure()
```

Comment: Why do you use `NavFigure.ax_tmp` instead of `self.ax_tmp`?

Comment: I have tried the same example using self.ax_tmp (instance variable) in place of class variable - same issue.

Comment: When I run your code, each press of the right arrow pans left by 100 units.  What are you seeing?

Comment: The issue only occurs after you zoom into the plot. Once you zoom in. The pan works to one or two right-arrow presses and becomes stagnant.

Comment: You're right.  That's very odd.  `ax.get_xlim()` returns the right value at the end of the function, but when we call it again next time, it returns the original value again.  It's the same object.  This is worth a bug report at matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks. I have opened a new bug report.